# how IBM cognos test data source connection when under ODBC ,does it invoke any API from my provided ODBC driver?

Tags: dll, odbc, driver, datasource, cognos

I have searched the web carefully and haven't found the answer ,so I put this problem here ,hope someone could help me .

Our company have developed an ODBC driver ,to use with our own database, but we just can't use it with IBM Cognos , I have added it as system dsn in 32 bit odbc administrator according to some tips from the web , but when click test the connection, I got the error function sequence error from DRIVER MANAGER of Microsoft .

I tested with postgre ODBC Driver , it could work .
I assume the Cognos  should call some APIs from my driver ,and it failed.
And I open the trace function provided in Microsoft ODBC Administrator (32bit) ,there is no file logged .

So my question here is the one in the title.
How does Cognos test connection ?
Call the specified ODBC Driver API ?
If so ,call which one ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: What version of Cognos (10.2, 11.0.13, etc)?
You may want to consider using JDBC so you can take advantage of DQM (dynamic query mode)

Comment: it doesn't matter now ,as I now could make cognos to log the invocation of ODBC  APIs ,and thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ah,I have found a solution to my own question . in the installation of place of your cognos ,in the bin directory ,find the file cogdmod.ini ,at the end of the file ,add these three lines :

```
[Trace]
Output=C:\Users\phony_name\Desktop\cognos.txt
Flags=1111111111
```

the output file path should exist before you let cognos log the activity for you .

Thus ,you could see which ODBC API cognos has called .